# HTML and CSS resizing on mobile with Codepen, but not after publishing on Github or Bluehost

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize, publish

For some reason,  I have a code that is completely identical and it works fine when I test it on codepen, but it will not resize at all when I bring it to github for publishing.

The codepen is: https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/ExaedBr?editors=1100

This is one extract of my CSS not properly resizing:

```
.mission2 p {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-family: 'roboto';
    padding: 4% 0% 0% 0%;
    clear: right;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

The actual website is located at: MFASP.com

I honestly have no idea what to look at for the cause of this, as both codes are exactly the same.

Comment: It seems to be resizing fine for me on the website. You are talking about the resizing via the `1.5vw`, right? For me on Chrome and Firefox this is resizing appropriately

Comment: Yes the 1.5VW is displaying fine on a desktop page, but once I open it in mobile it contains the same sized font as the desktop, which distorts the site a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a bit of digging and found the solution.  I had not been used to using

`meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`

this tag, but adding it into my html had allowed the browser to resize.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the issue you are having, you need to add a `viewport` meta tag to your page `head`. This is most commonly `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

So your html would have the Doctype followed by something along the lines of..

```
<head>
...
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Daniel, I didn't see your solution before posting this. I'm glad you found the solution!